# Want to show a HTML table with fancybox gallery

Tags: html, fancybox-2

This is my first post here.
Want to get help on following issues:

1. Want to show a HTML table below every image of gallery. How can I do this.
2. When I want to show a webpage with image of gallery, first page is always ok but fancybox does not displays others webpages properly. How can I solve this problem.

A newbie for fancybox so please show the full procedure.

Comment: With the risk of sounding bitchy, you don't do the same thing to a car repairman. You: "My car won't start, what is the problem" repairman: "Ok, but where is the car?". We can guess all day, but to get precise answers, the best thing to do, is to show your actual code or at least the problem area. http://jsfiddle.net is good for setting up quick examples. Still, you could check e.g. firebug console to see if it's giving errors. You could isolate only the code that is giving you trouble and then see if that works on its own. Html validation isn't a bad idea either http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Please update your question with code or link to problematic webpage, otherwise you are not asking for help but for someone to do the job for you.